# Can't get realtime data after deleting the document

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I'm going to add like feature to the app in React + Redux + Firebase. When clicking "Like" (`createLike`) works in realtime but `deleteLike` doesn't work in realtime. With reloading, it shows "Like" after clicking "Unlike". The issue is **deleteDestory is not working asynchronously in Redux + Firestore**.

The code:
I define `currentUser` from Firestore user and `id` is fetched from params. The user likes the content of each article.

```
  onLike = value => {
    const { id, currentUser } = this.props;
    if (value) {
      this.props.createLike(currentUser.uid, id);
    } else {
      this.props.deleteLike(currentUser.uid, id);
    }
  };

  renderLike = () => {
    const { like } = this.props;

      if (like.is_like) {
        return (
          <button
            className="like"
            onClick={() => this.onLike(true)}
          >
            <span>Like</span>
          </button>
        );
      } else {
        return (
          <button
            className="unlike"
            onClick={() => this.onLike(false)}
          >
            <span>Unlike</span>
          </button>
        );
      }
  };
```

The Redux code:

```
// Fetch like
export function fetchLike(id) {
  return dispatch => {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        likesRef
          .where("uid", "==", user.uid)
          .where("cid", "==", id)
          .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            if (querySnapshot) {
              querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                dispatch({ type: FETCH_LIKE, payload: doc.data() });
              });
            }
          });
      }
    });
  };
}

// Delete like
export function deleteLike(uid, cid) {
  return dispatch => {
    likesRef
      .where("uid", "==", uid)
      .where("cid", "==", cid)
      .get()
      .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
          doc.ref.delete();
        });
        dispatch({ type: DELETE_LIKE });
      });
  };
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { FETCH_LIKE } from "../actions";

const initialState = {
  is_like: true
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LIKE:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### Addition

I add `createLike` here.

```
// Create Like
export function createLike(uid, cid) {
  return dispatch => {
    likesRef
      .add({
        uid: uid,
        cid: cid,
        created_at: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
      })
      .then(function() {
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_LIKE });
      });
  };
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `createLike` function.

Comment: @Jacob I have added `createLike`.

Answer (score 0):

I have it done.

```
import { FETCH_LIKE, DELETE_LIKE } from "../actions";
const initialState = {
  is_like: true
};
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_LIKE:
      return action.payload;
    case DELETE_LIKE:
      return { is_like: true };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```